# Fatal error due to file permissions

Tags: errors

Please help me resolve this as soon as possible.
I'm not a developer and coder. but trying to find the solution for this.
I'm getting an error like this:

```
The dr9.in page isn’t working

dr9.in is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

[image]

When i Checked the error logs.. i got error saying that:

> [16-Nov-2016 23:10:42 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning: 
>   require(/home/technlrq/public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/technlrq/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21 [17-Nov-2016
>   00:00:50 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/technlrq/public_html/wp-includes/load.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')
>   in /home/technlrq/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21 [17-Nov-2016
>   00:05:40 Etc/GMT] PHP Warning: 
>   require(/home/technlrq/public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/technlrq/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21 [17-Nov-2016
>   00:27:37 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/technlrq/public_html/wp-includes/load.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')
>   in /home/technlrq/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21

Comment: contact hosting provider with that message.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a back up of your site, and then replacing the Wordpress core files. Download a fresh copy from word press.org and replace the files in the WP–admin folder and WP–includes folder. You can also replace any files in the immediate public_HTML folder excluding WP–config.php. This might resolve the issue.

Additionally, I would think about what happened before the error started appearing. Did you install any new plug-ins or update anything? You can disable all the plug-ins by renaming the plugin  folder (found in the WP–content folder). This is generally a good area to try as part of your standard troubleshooting.